# trying to understand Apache <Directory /> directive. Linux

Tags: apache-2.4

My understanding of `<Directory /> Some directives... </Directory>`
is that it describes access to ROOT of a linux filesystem.

What I have done to test this is

```
<Directory />
   AllowOverride None
   Require all granted 
</Directory>
```

and removed all other `Directory` config.

Then tried to access a file on a filesystem without sucess.

NOTE: I have restarted the apache.

Tried to remove `<Directory>` config completely still the same. Where from the Apache loads `<Directory>` conf if none is defined?

In Apache documentation is written that the default access for `<Directory "/">` is to permit all access. Still it is not the case.

My test is done on Ubuntu 16.04, Apache 2.4.18.

Comment: Typically your log file(s) will explain why access is denied, but one thing to keep in mind is that Apache directives can't grant access where things like file system permissions (and other ACL's) deny access

Comment: @HBruijn thanks for interest in helping me. Thing is that even though I removed ALL <Directory> options, Apache still tries to server content from /var/www/html. Are some defaults compiled in with distro defaults?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`Directory`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#directory) directive does not set where from apache httpd will load content, that is governed by the [`DocumentRoot`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#documentroot) directive. The default according to the manual is `/usr/local/apache/htdocs` but in fact it is [compile time setting](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/programs/configure.html) that many Linux distributions set to `/var/www/` or a subdirectory therein

Comment: This is form Apache docs.
Note that the default access for <Directory "/"> is to permit all access. This means that Apache httpd will serve any file mapped from an URL. It is recommended that you change this with a block such as

<Directory "/">
  Require all denied
</Directory>
and then override this for directories you want accessible. See the Security Tips page for more details.

Comment: @titus If you don't configure any restrictions in Apache (and set `DocumentRoot /`) your webserver will serve every file that the file-system permissions allow the apache user acces to.